# Metodos jquery no se ejecutan en mi vista en .net

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2017, webforms

Tengo estos metodos en mi js:

```
function soloNumeros(e) {
            var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
            return (key >= 48 && key <= 57);
        }

        function soloPegarNumeros(n) {
            permitidos = /[^0-9.]/;
            if (permitidos.test(n.value)) {
                alert("Solo se puede ingresar numeros");
                n.value = "";
                n.focus();
            }
        }

        $("#txtDNI").keypress(soloNumeros(event));

        $("#txtDNI").blur(soloPegarNumeros(this));
```

Y en mi vista tengo esto:

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" autofocus="autofocus" runat="server" ID="txtDNI" MaxLength="8" AutoPostBack="true"/><br />
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es validar que no se escriba ni se pegue letras en el textbox "txtDni". Pero no sé porque no agarra los metodos de jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene un ejemplo del típico ¿Quién es `this`?
Agrega los métodos en un `$(document).ready()` y ejecutalos desde el mismo evento ( `keypress()` o `blur()` ) que los dispara.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#txtDNI").keypress(function(e){
    console.log("solo numeros");
  try{
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
    return (key >= 48 && key <= 57);
  }
  catch(ex){
  }   
  });
 $("#txtDNI").blur(function(n){
  permitidos = /[^0-9.]/;
  if (permitidos.test(n.value)) {
    alert("Solo se puede ingresar numeros");
    n.value = "";
    $(n).focus();
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  runat="server" ID="txtDNI" MaxLength="8" AutoPostBack="true"/><br />
```